# i try to redirect my controller to ('Admin/login'), but it's did not work

Tags: php, html

An uncaught Exception was encountered

> Type: ParseError
>   Message: syntax error, unexpected 'redirect' (T_STRING)
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\webku\application\controllers\Admin.php
>   Line Number: 28

Backtrace:

```
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\webku\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

this is my **controller**:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('back/login');
    }

    public function proseslogin_admin()
    {
        //Panggil Model
        $this->load->model('M_user');

        $username = $this->input->post('user');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $cek = $this->M_user->cek_login($username,$password)->num_rows();
        //cek kondisi nya apakah ada yang login atau tidak
        if($cek > 0)//jika benar
        {

        }
        else//jika salah
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan','Maaf Username dan Password Salah !')
            redirect('Admin/login');
        }
    }
}
```

this is my **model**:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_user extends CI_Model
{
    public function cek_login($username,$password) 
    {
        $data = array
        (
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => sha1($password)
        );
        return $this->db->get_where('user', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You miss a semicolon before redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed semicolon `;` near

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('pesan','Maaf Username dan Password Salah !')
```

It should be

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('pesan','Maaf Username dan Password Salah !');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed the semicolon.

```
public function login()
{
    $this->load->view('back/login');
}

public function proseslogin_admin()
{
    //Panggil Model
    $this->load->model('M_user');

    $username = $this->input->post('user');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $cek = $this->M_user->cek_login($username,$password)->num_rows();
    //cek kondisi nya apakah ada yang login atau tidak
    if($cek > 0)//jika benar
    {

    }
    else//jika salah
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan','Maaf Username dan Password Salah !');
        redirect('Admin/login');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not careful, thanks a lot :D